# php mail resume and other details with ajax submit and captcha

Tags: php, ajax, email, captcha

I have a form with captcha but it will not work submit in ajax mode where as it will work well in normal submit mode.

```
<form action="#" name="MYFORM" id="MYFORM"> 
  <label>Name</label> 
  <input name="name" size="30" type="text" id="name"> <br clear="all" /> 
  <label>Email</label> <input name="email" size="30" type="text" id="email"> <br clear="all" /> 
    <div id="wrap" align="center"> 
      <img src="get_captcha.php" alt="" id="captcha" /> 
      <br clear="all" /> 
      <input name="code" type="text" id="code"> 
    </div> 
  <img src="refresh.jpg" width="25" alt="" id="refresh" /> 
  <br clear="all" /><br clear="all" /> 
  <label>&nbsp;</label> 
  <input value="Send" type="submit" id="Send"> 
</form>
```

Comment: can you attach some of your code here?

Comment: this doesn't tell us anything. Post the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce this error, and list the error you're receiving

Comment: <form action="#" name="MYFORM" id="MYFORM">
 <label>Name</label>
 <input name="name" size="30" type="text" id="name">
 <br clear="all" />
 <label>Email</label>
 <input name="email" size="30" type="text" id="email">
 <br clear="all" />
 <div id="wrap" align="center">
  <img src="get_captcha.php" alt="" id="captcha" />
 <br clear="all" />
  <input name="code" type="text" id="code">
 </div>
 <img src="refresh.jpg" width="25" alt="" id="refresh" />
  
 <br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />
 <label>&nbsp;</label>
 <input value="Send" type="submit" id="Send">
</form>

Comment: @andikatdennis Please add the relevant HTML, Javascript, and PHP code to the body of the question, along with any error messages or other observations you have made from debugging your code.